# Alternative to using a triple pointer

Tags: c

I have a pointer to a structure in my code. I want to return an array of such pointers in an API. Something like

```
Status GetData(MyStructure*** data, int*lengthOfArray)
  {
     *data = malloc(sizeof(MyStructure*)* arbitaryNumber));
     for(i=0....)
     {
       (*data)[i] = pointerToMyStructure;
     }
  }
```

Is there an alternative to this? My API has to have a return type Status. So the only way forward I see at the moment is to turn into a [3 star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: It's the way it is and it's ok.

Comment: How do you plan to use `lengthOfArray`?

Comment: lengthOfArray gets filled with arbitaryNumber, in other words it tells the API caller, the length of the array it just got

Comment: Before you start "fixing" this by hiding pointer types inside typedefs, *don't*. What you have, though it takes a little gray matter to picture, speaks well. You have a dynamic pointer sequence (`**`) that must be passed as an in/out (`*`). You're code looks correct to do this. Just be clear when documenting how it works. If you have the freedom to change the functional interface, [you have other options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23414948/1322972) that are a better fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you are returning the length of the array as well, and because the array of `struct` pointers and the length are related, you could build a special `struct` to get both items from your API together, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    MyStructure **data;
    int length;
} GetDataArg_t;
```

Now you can change your API like this:

```
Status GetData(GetDataArg_t *args) {
    args->length = arbitaryNumbdr;
    args->data = malloc(sizeof(MyStructure*)* arbitaryNumbdr));
    for(i=0....) {
        args->data[i] = pointerToMytructure;
    }
}
```

The call of your API would look like this:

```
GetDataArg_t args;
if (GetData(&args) == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 pinning the tightly-related data together in this fashion is a strong move. If at all feasible to change the functional interface, this is worth pursuing.